# Find next shortest path in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I want to find a couple of paths between 2 nodes. I don't just want the shortest path or all paths with the shortest length (allShortestPaths). I need all the shortest paths and the next shortest paths. Since it is not possible to set allShortestPaths with minimal length different from 0/1.
"allShortestPaths(...) does not support a minimal length different from 0 or 1"

It could be solved with projections or apoc.path.expandConfig, however we have a database with 14 million nodes and 56 million relationships, so when I tried doing this, we could deliver paths with lengths of 4 in 20-30 seconds and lengths of more than 4 was not possible. Is there a way to find a subset of all paths that are shortest, but also fast to execute?

Lets say my source node is A, and target node is F, and I wanted the 3 shortest paths, the 3 paths would then be:
(A-f), (A-C-F), (A-B-F)

[image: example graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that yen's algorithm would be very suitable after I tried using projections (which was pretty fast)
https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/yens/